# creating a function that will move an object from one array (of objects) to another each time a button of the selected product is pressed

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, components, jsx

I want to create a `function` that will move an `object` from one `array` (of `objects`) to another each time a button of the selected product is pressed
The shopping list will display in the `HomePage component` (1 `array` of `objects`)
The cart list of the selected products will display in the `Cart component` (additional array)

Did I defined something in a wrong way in the `state`? or in the `return`?

its really important for me to keep it the simple way like I did, because I want to understand before I move on... also with ***no routers or hooks!***
thanks! (:

App.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Cart from './components/Cart.js';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage.js';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    productsList: [
      { product: 'T-shirt', cost: '12$' },
      { product: 'Shoes', cost: '45$' },
      { product: 'Haircut Machine', cost: '60$' }
    ],
    cartList: [{ product: '', cost: '' }]
  }

  add = () => {
    this.props.add(this.state.index)
  }

  addToCart = (i) => {
    cartList = this.state.productsList.filter((element, index) => (index != i));
    this.setState({ productsList: [...cartList] })
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.productsList.map((element) => {
          return <HomePage product={element.product} cost={element.cost} index={i} add={this.addToCart} />

        })}
        <Cart />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

HomePage.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class HomePage extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      product: '',
      cost: '',
      index: props.index
    }
  }

  render(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Price: {this.props.product}</div>
        <div>Product: {this.props.cost}</div>
        <button onClick={this.add}>Add To Cart</button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Cart.js (This component will hold and show the new products objects array)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Cart extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: You dont have `add` method defined and in `HomePage` component.

Comment: Did you mean to pass `this.props.add` as a click handler in the `Homepage` component?

Comment: Yes, `this.add` method is not defined in your `HomePage`

Comment: Since you are the one creating the data, use some unique `id`s for the items and do not struggle with indices. You want to remove an item from `products` and add it to `cartList`? Another thing is, do not set your props to the local state. I guess you are going to do that in `HomePage`?